# how to bind data to ng-keyup value to its function

Tags: angularjs

please help me. How can i bind data to `ng-keyup` value to function

```
 <input type="email" ng-model="c_emails" ng-keyup="Getvaliedemail($event)" required />

 $scope.Getvaliedemail = function ($event) {

        var valp = $event.key;
        if(value.length>3){ 
           //code goes here 
        }
 }
```

Here  `var valp = $event.key;`  values coming  as a after  that b

Comment: What is value ?

Comment: from the textbox if user enter keyword like abc i want this abc at var vap how can i bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to pass the value of the input model to `Getvaliedemail` so I think this will work (you can still access `$event`):

```
<input type="email" ng-model="c_emails" ng-keyup="Getvaliedemail($event, c_emails)" required />

$scope.Getvaliedemail = function (event, data) {
    var evt = event;
    var valp = data;
    if(valp.length>3){}
}
```

**Notes:**

`ngKeyup` is related with the on keyup event. With that said, if you just want to track changes to the value of the input, then you should use `ngChange` which is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="c_emails" ng-change="Getvaliedemail(c_emails)" required />

$scope.Getvaliedemail = function (data) {
    var valp = data;
    if(valp.length>3){}
}
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should note that `ngChange` will not be evaluated in some cases, according to [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
> - if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply at my comment this would do the work for you:

```
 <input type="email" ng-model="c_emails" ng-change="Getvaliedemail(c_emails)" required />


$scope.Getvaliedemail = function(value) {
  if(value.length <= 3) return;
  var valp = value;
}
```

There's no need to use `ng-keyup` directive.